# Let G be a simple graph and G' the graph in which every two vertices

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple graph and $G'$ the graph in which every two adjacent vertices in $G$ are connected  by $k$ edges. Prove that

$T(G')=k^{v(G)-1}T(G)$,
where $T$ is the number of spanning trees and $v$ is the number of vertices.

I think that we should take into consideration theory that if $G$ is a tree then |$E(G)|=v(G)-1$, but it's only my thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi: E(G') \to E(G)$ be the map which takes an edge between $v$ and $w$ (in $G'$) and maps it to the unique edge between $v$ and $w$ (in $G$). Note that $\phi$ naturally induces a map $\tilde{\phi}:T(G')\to T(G)$ by simply acting by $\phi$ on every edge in a given tree.

Now, all you have to check is that $\tilde{\phi}$ is surjective and $k^{v(G)-1}$-to-one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have only one question - from where we know it is $v(G)-1$ ? I know that it is written in the post, but I don't know why we know the G is a tree or maybe there is another reason.

Comment: A tree has exactly as many edges as the number of vertices minus one. Hence, a spanning tree on $G$ will have $v(G)-1$ edges.